# Duplicated env variable names in pod definition, what is the precedence rule to determine the final value?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, configmap

Using Kubernetes 1.19.3, I initialize env variable values using 3 different ways:

- `env` field with explicit key/value in the pod definition
- `envFrom` using `configMapRef` and `secretRef`

When a key name is duplicated, as shown in the example below, `DUPLIK1` and `DUPLIK2` are defined multiple times with different values.

What is the precedence rule that Kubernetes uses to assign the final value to the variable?

```sh
# create some test Key/Value configs and Key/Value secrets
kubectl create configmap myconfigmap --from-literal=DUPLIK1=myConfig1 --from-literal=CMKEY1=CMval1 --from-literal=DUPLIK2=FromConfigMap -n mydebugns

kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-literal=SECRETKEY1=SECval1 --from-literal=SECRETKEY2=SECval2 --from-literal=DUPLIK2=FromSecret -n mydebugns

# create a test pod
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -n mydebugns -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod1
spec:
  containers:
    - name: container1
      image: busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      env:
      - name: DUPLIK1
        value: "Key/Value defined in field env"
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: myconfigmap
      - secretRef:
          name: mysecret          
  restartPolicy: Never
EOF
```

Show environement variables values. The result is deterministic. Deleting resources + recreate always end up with the same result.

```sh
kubectl logs pod/pod1 -n mydebugns

CMKEY1=CMval1
DUPLIK1=Key/Value defined in field env
DUPLIK2=FromSecret
SECRETKEY1=SECval1
SECRETKEY2=SECval2
```

Cleanup test resources

```sh
kubectl delete pod/pod1 -n mydebugns
kubectl delete cm/myconfigmap  -n mydebugns
kubectl delete secret/mysecret -n mydebugns
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#environment-variables):

> `envVar`: List of environment variables to set in the container.
> Cannot be updated.

> `envFrom`: List of sources to populate environment variables in the
> container. The keys defined within a source must be a C_IDENTIFIER.
> All invalid keys will be reported as an event when the container is
> starting. When a key exists in multiple sources, the value associated
> with the last source will take precedence. **Values defined by an Env
> with a duplicate key will take precedence. Cannot be updated.**

The above link clearly states the `env` will take precedence over `envFrom` and cannot be updated.

Also, when a referenced key is present in multiple resources, the value associated with the last source will override all previous values.

Based on the above, the result you are seeing is expected behavior:

1. `DUPLIK1` is added as `env` field and thus cannot be updated
2. `DUPLIK2` is added as `envFrom` and so the one from the secret takes precedence as it is defined at the last

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much. I swaped the declarative positions to have `configMapRef` as last and indeed `DUPLIK2=fromConfigMap`. BTW, where does the docs page (/reference/generated) you gave come from? The doc I used to see looks different (no generated): https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/. What is the difference between these 2 docs?

Comment: They are referenced here in the kubernetes.io: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/ and I believe the reference docs are generated from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master where each version has its own specific branch. `1.20` for example are present at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.20.

Comment: Was trying to find the same page you showed  [WORKLOAD APIS / Container v1 core](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#container-v1-core) in the non generated doc. But could not. I wonder when I should use one or the other (generated vs non-generated doc)

Comment: The kubernetes.io I believe includes technical concepts as well while the generated one mostly include API reference and should mostly be required if you are working with some resource which are not fully matured. For example, a resource may be in `beta` in some version and we would then need to look at the respective version of the API reference.