# Precedence rule in container env list with duplicate name key in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, configmap

Related to [Duplicated env variable names in pod definition, what is the precedence rule to determine the final value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66288565/3288890)

I have a deployment spec with a repeated env name, see below:

```
containers:
  - name: c1
  ...
    env:
      - name: DUP1
        value: hello1
      - name: DUP1
        value: hello2
```

Can I expect the second DUP1 key to always be the one set on the pod? e.g. echo $DUP1 == "hello2". It seems to be the case but I can't find validation about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order maintains like this, it will always be set as `hello2`

> Note: Environment variables may reference each other, **however ordering is important**. Variables making use of others defined in the same context must come later in the list. Similarly, avoid circular references.

so if the order changes for the value like this

```
            - name: DUP1
              value: hello2
            - name: DUP1
              value: hello1
```

it will be set as `hello1`

[inject-environment-variable-container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)

Answer (score 1):

Have recently tested this -- in my case the precedence is reversed. Am not sure why it is the case and apparently not so for the other responders but, in yaml:

```
env: 
 - name: key1
   value: value1
 - name: key1
   value: value2
```

is rendering

```
containers:
- env:
  - name: key1
    value: value1
```

Answer (score 0):

In kubernetes, the last value persists. So

```yaml
containers:
  - name: myContaienr
  ...
    env:
      - name: Key1
        value: This_is_the_first_value
      - name: key1
        value: This_will_write_the_previous_value
```